Replace null values with values random values from a table
The results from a SQL query produces the following table:
|SEDOL |   ISIN      | Cash |
=============================
|ZZZ0072|GB00B7JYLW09| null |
-----------------------------
|CASH   |GB00B7JYLW09| null |
-----------------------------
|ZZZ0072|GB00B7JYLW09| null |
-----------------------------
|ZZZ0009|GB00B7JYLW09| null |
-----------------------------

I would like help with a query that will replace the null values in the Cash field with values (any value) from the table testtable with field 'IsCash' and  to return the following table:
=============================
|SEDOL |   ISIN      | Cash |
=============================
|ZZZ0072|GB00B7JYLW09|150146|
-----------------------------
|CASH   |GB00B7JYLW09| 182  |
-----------------------------
|ZZZ0072|GB00B7JYLW09| 1190 |
-----------------------------
|ZZZ0009|GB00B7JYLW09| 2000 |
-----------------------------

The testtable is:
|    IsCash  |
==============
|     36     |
--------------
|   150146   |
--------------
|    182     |
--------------
|   2000     |
--------------
|   200952   |
--------------
|   200000   |
--------------
|   350000   |
--------------
|   150000   |
--------------
|    1190    |
--------------

I think I would need to apply the ISNULL statement to the 'Cash' field, but I'm not sure on the clause used to issue the replace statement from the testtable with the IsCash field.
Results could easily appear as follows, because I just want any random value from the testtable from field IsCash to appear in the Cash field as follows
| SEDOL  |  ISIN      |  Cash |
===============================
|ZZZ0072 |GB00B7JYLW09| 200952|
-------------------------------
|  CASH  |GB00B7JYLW09| 200000|
-------------------------------
|ZZZ0072 |GB00B7JYLW09| 150000|
-------------------------------
|ZZZ0009 |GB00B7JYLW09| 1190  |
-------------------------------


Read about "update" statements

@siggemannen, thanks for getting in touch. All I want is a query that will add data to the field 'Cash', from the table, 'testtable' with any random value from the field 'IsCash'

Something like this: https://dbfiddle.uk/3L9BFgvg

How random do you want it to be? you can just cross join and update but that might get all rows the same value

@JonasMetzler, I look at your suggestion, which appears to be close to what I would like, however, each value for cash is the same i.e. 200952. Could it me modified to show individual random values from the test table? Does that make sense. I have updated the question

@JonasMetzler, are you still able to assist with this question?

Anyone able to expand on what @JonasMetzler created?

I was just writing the answer, but you're being kinda pushy, so i deleted it

@siggemannen, sorry about that, it's just that I'm under a lot pressure with my job right now, and I'm very stressed out.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

@siggemannen Same to me, much too unkind.

Please try the following solution.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, SEDOL  VARCHAR(512), ISIN  VARCHAR(512), Cash VARCHAR(512));
INSERT INTO @tbl (SEDOL, ISIN, Cash) VALUES 
('ZZZ0072', 'GB00B7JYLW09', NULL),
('CASH', 'GB00B7JYLW09', NULL),
('ZZZ0072', 'GB00B7JYLW09', NULL),
('ZZZ0009', 'GB00B7JYLW09', NULL),
('Test', 'Test', 'Test');

DECLARE @cash TABLE (IsCash varchar(512));
INSERT INTO @cash (IsCash) VALUES
('36'),     
('150146'),   
('182'),     
('2000'),     
('200952'),   
('200000'),   
('350000'),   
('150000'),   
('1190'); 
-- DDL and sample data population, end

;WITH rs AS
(
   SELECT *
      , seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY NEWID())
   FROM @cash
)
UPDATE t
SET Cash = rs.IsCash
FROM @tbl AS t INNER JOIN rs ON rs.seq = t.ID;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

Output



ID
SEDOL
ISIN
Cash




1
ZZZ0072
GB00B7JYLW09
150000


2
CASH
GB00B7JYLW09
350000


3
ZZZ0072
GB00B7JYLW09
2000


4
ZZZ0009
GB00B7JYLW09
1190


5
Test
Test
36




Aside: The results may be less than ideal if @tbl has more rows than @cash, but you used the provided sample data so that's what the OP gets.

@Patterson, Glad to hear that the proposed solution is working for you. Please don't forget to mark it as Answer.

Using @JonasMetzler's data, here's one potential solution:
update t
  set cash = case when t.cash is null then x.IsCash else t.cash end
FROM (select (row_number() over(order by NEWID()) % (select COUNT(*) from testtable)) AS sort, *
      from  tableName t
  ) t
inner join (
      select row_number() over(order by NEWID()) - 1 AS sort, * from testtable
   ) x
  ON x.sort = t.sort

Basically you randomly sort on both sides to create a "sort"-column on which you then join to update the value. If there's a lot more rows in source than in Cash-table, we try to distribute the values by using a modulo

thanks for sticking with me. I'm reviewing your query now. Thanks

@yitzhak, is it essential that the ID your suggestion needs to INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY?

@Patterson, Not exactly. Just any table needs a primary key to be in a first normal form (1NF).

@YitzhakKhabinsky, I tested the solution and it works perfectly. Thanks also to Siggemanned
